# 'Invalid argument' error when using 'chown apache' on web server folder

Tags: apache, chown

On a mac in terminal when executing:

```
chown apache uploads/
```

I get the error:

```
chown: apache: Invalid argument
```

The foder is on a shared web server. I need to change the owner of the folder because otherwise my PHP script for creating simple text files will return a permission denied error. Please don't suggest chmodding the folder to 777 (which does work), since almost all advice against it.

Is it possible that the server doesn't run scripts as the user 'apache'? How can I find this out?

Answer (score 0):

There are two things you might want to check:

1) Is there a user called `apache`? Maybe it's `httpd`. You can search `/etc/passwd`. (Or whatever your platform uses to store user names, you didn't mention your operating system.)

2) What user do scripts run as? You can check this by running a test script. For example:

```
 #/bin/bash
 echo Content-Type: text/plain
 echo
 id -a
```

If you save this as `test.cgi` and put it in a CGI directory, you should be able to run it and get it to tell you what user it's running as.

Answer (score 0):

"Invalid argument" makes me think this directory is on an HFS+ volume with owners disabled; you won't be able to change it in that case.  You may be able to switch owners on, although it's possible that requires reformatting.

(The advice to check `/etc/passwd` is wrong, or at least inaccurate, on OS X; you need `dscl . list /Users`.)